# Click based movement not working

Tags: c#, xna

I have the player moving towards where i have clicked. But when i arrive at the position of where i clicked, the sprite just flickers back and forth. I assume its because the sprite is going past this point, going back to it, going past it again, then going back constantly creating a 'flickering'. Any ideas why?

*****SOLVED*****************
******UPDATED CODE**********

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace AsteroidAvoider
{
    class Player
    {
        public Vector2 position, distance, mousePosition;
        public float speed;
        public float rotation;
        public Texture2D playerImage;
        public MouseState mouseState;

        public Player(Texture2D playerImage, Vector2 position, float speed)
        {
            this.playerImage = playerImage;
            this.position = position;
            this.speed = speed;
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            mouseState = Mouse.GetState();

            float speedForThisFrame = speed;

            if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                mousePosition.X = mouseState.X;
                mousePosition.Y = mouseState.Y;
            }

            if ((mousePosition - position).Length() < speed)
                speedForThisFrame = 0;

            if ((mousePosition - position).Length() > speed)
                speedForThisFrame = 2.0f;

            distance = mousePosition - position;
            distance.Normalize();

            rotation = (float)Math.Atan2(distance.Y, distance.X);

            position += distance * speedForThisFrame;
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(playerImage, position, null, Color.White, rotation, new Vector2(playerImage.Width / 2, playerImage.Height / 2), 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your speed and does the behavior change if you reduce it?

Comment: Speed is 2f, no it doesn't change if i reduce the speed, the flickering effect still takes place

Comment: @Jake You should post the answer part as an actual answer to your own question. It is normal practice here on StackOverflow, and it may also get you some additional reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normalized vector , if I remember correctly should always have a total length of 1 (Vector2.Length() returns the length of the entire vector2 by the way)
A simple solution would be making your unit reduce the speed of movement if within the range of the mouse , for example

```
float speedForThisFrame = speed;
if((mousePosition-position).Length() < speed) speedForThisFrame = (mousePosition-position).Length();
```

and use speedForThisFrame for the position offsetting.

Answer (score 1):

You need a collider, a `Rectangle` that represents your player, so when this collider contains your `mousePosition` or the click coordinate (you can easily detect it using `Rectangle.Contains` method) you simply set player's speed as 0, avoiding the flickering.

Of course, when the clicked coordinate changes, you have to set the previous player's speed.

Comment: The logic seems like it would work. I put "bounds = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, playerImage.Width, playerImage.Height);" in the Player constructor after initializing it up top, then in the Update i have             "if (bounds.Contains((int)mousePosition.X, (int)mousePosition.Y))
            {
                speed = 0;
            }" but the problem still exists.

Comment: Are you sure that bounds is initialized correctly? You have to ensure that playerImage is initialized, too, otherwise your rectangle will have no width and height. Try to use a breakpoint to see if the program enters bounds.Contains.

Comment: Ok, and what about the breakpoint? Does the program enters bound.Contains? Edit the question with your current code :)

Comment: Good! But I still don't understand why my solution didn't work.